# Failed to send instantiate transaction and get notifications within the timeout period. undefined[fabric1.0 k8s]

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy Hyperledger fabric 1.0.5 on k8s, and use the balance transfer to test it. Everything is right before instantiate-chaincode, and I get this:

```
[2019-01-02 23:23:14.392] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to send instantiate transaction and get notifications within the timeout period. undefined
[2019-01-02 23:23:14.393] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to order the transaction. Error code: undefined
```

and I use `kubectl logs` to get the peer0's log which is like this:

```
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 61a Failed connecting to orderer2.orderer1:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 61b Failed connecting to orderer1.orderer1:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 61c Failed connecting to orderer0.orderer1:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
[deliveryClient] connect -> DEBU 61d Connected to 
[deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 61e Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [orderer2.orderer1:7050 orderer1.orderer1:7050 orderer0.orderer1:7050]
```

I checked the connectivity of `orderer0:7050` and found no problem.

What should I do next？

Thank for help！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe what runbook you followed to deploy Hyperledger Fabric but looks like your pods cannot find each other [through DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). If you are following Kubernetes standards your pods should be in the `orderer1` namespace and hopefully, you have Kubernetes [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for `orderer0`, `orderer1`, and `orderer2`.

You can read more about communication between the Fabric components [here](http://www.think-foundry.com/deploy-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-part-1/) in the "Communication between Fabric components" section. Also, read on the "Work around the chaincode sandbox" where it shows you a workaround for `--dns-search`.

Comment: thanks! I found that I misunderstood the service configuration of k8s.But I have a new problem....i get the error messages like that

Comment: If it’s another problem ask another SO question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like firewall problem.

In my case to run hlf on k8s, I disabled firewall service.